# Will I make it out in time?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, grid, simulation

*Inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/138068/kill-it-with-fire).*

### Background

The [evil farmer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/138068/kill-it-with-fire) has decided to burn your wheat field down in order to drive up the prices. To ensure total destruction, he has also soaked your field in gasoline. Even more unfortunately, you happened to be walking on the field when it was lit on fire, and you must get out quickly to survive.

### Challenge

Given a field containing wheat, fire and your location, determine if you can make it out of the field in time.

A field consists of wheat (here represented by `.`) and fire (`F`). Here your location is marked with a `O`. For example:

```
...F...F
F.......
........
.F......
....O...
...F....
........
.F....F.
```

Every second you move to any adjacent cell (but not diagonally), and every fire spreads to every adjacent cell. If you can't move to a cell that will not be on fire, you die. If you make it out of the field, you survive. Let's see what happens in this example:

```
...F...F
F.......
........
.F......
....O...
...F....
........
.F....F.

..FFF.FF
FF.F...F
FF......
FFF.....
.F.F.O..
..FFF...
.F.F..F.
FFF..FFF

FFFFFFFF
FFFFF.FF
FFFF...F
FFFF....
FF.FF.O.
.FFFFFF.
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF

FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
FFFFF.FF
FFFFF.FF
FFFFFFFO
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF

FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFO <-- you made it out and survived, barely
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
```

### Rules

- Your input is the field as a grid. You may choose any input format, including a string with line separators or a 2D array.

  - You may **not** take as input the locations for fire and/or yourself.
  - You may use any 3 distinct values as wheat, fire and your position, including non-strings for array input.
  - Fields are always at least 1x1 in size, rectangular and contain no invalid characters.
  - Any field will contain exactly one of the value representing your location, and every other position may or may not be fire.
- Your output is one of two distinct values for "you survive" or "you die", as usual in [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem).
- Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

### Test cases

#### Survived

```
O
```

```
....
.O..
....
```

```
FFFFF
.....
..O..
.....
```

```
FFFF
FFFO
FFFF
```

```
.F....
......
......
.F....
..O...
.FF...
.F....
..FF..
```

```
...F...F
F.......
........
.F......
....O...
...F....
........
.F....F.
```

#### Didn't survive

```
FFF
FOF
FFF
```

```
F.F
.O.
F.F
```

```
....F
.....
..O..
.....
F....
```

```
.F....F.
........
........
F..O....
........
.....F..
```

```
...F...F
F......F
........
.F......
....O...
...F....
........
.F....F.
```

```
F..F
.O..
FF..
```

Comment: This is kinda like the 'Meteor Showers' USACO problem

Comment: I don't see why someone downvoted

Comment: @OliverNi Probably because of the inspired by comment, instead of reading it they saw that thought it was a chameleon and down voted.

Comment: To both downvoters, please explain why my challenge is bad.

Comment: Why is there this restriction: "You may not take as input the locations for fire and/or yourself."? It just adds task to find O and Fs in input

Comment: @DeadPossum Because I feel like it would simplify the challenge too much and make it a bit too broad. Feel free to disagree, though; if others agree with you I might change the restriction.

Comment: I agree with Pietu1998, I also feel that the restriction is highly appropriate.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder `Any field will contain exactly one of your location`

Comment: In all the truthy test cases you can escape following a straight line. Actually the general problem is more complicated if you have to consider non-straight paths. Since that seems to be the case, you should add a test case where you can escape but not following a straight path (or clarify that only straight paths need be considered)

Comment: @LuisMendo If it is possible to escape when the farmer turns, it's always possible for him/her to escape in a straight line. For instance, let's say the farmer is trying to escape to the right of the field. When the farmer moves one space down, some fire will spread downwards; then, the farmer's situation is the same as the initial position (plus more fire).

Comment: I, speaking as the evil farmer, would never soak the field in gasoline first.  I would tie you up, place you in the exact center of the field, and then start fires at the corners.  Then I would watch as the fire *slowly* moves toward you so I can enjoy your terror longer.  Much more evil that way.

Comment: Additionally, the above plan makes it impossible for you to get out alive, as you will be tied up.

Comment: @LuisMendo When writing the challenge I did notice that considering straight paths is sufficient. I thought about mentioning it, but I decided to let the answerers figure it out.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Snails, 15 bytes

```
\Oo!{.,fee7.,\F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85LzMwp/v8/xr9SsVpPJy011VxPJ8bt/389Nz0g4NLTQ6Fggv4QnhuKIIgLAA)

`1` means survival while `0` means death.

Since it is impossible to outrun the fire, it is never useful to try to go around it. The best route is always a straight line. So there are only four possible choices of escape route. To determine if a direction is safe, we check for any `F` in the "fire cone" pointing in that direction.

Comment: O_o Can you provide a testing link? This seems very short.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder OK. It's a language specialized for [tag:grid] [tag:decision-problem]s after all.

Comment: The code is almost saying: "Oy!"... "phew"...

Comment: Because snails are the perfect choice for, you know, outrunning a fire...

Comment: @feersum In the "try it online" link, I tried the following 3-line wheat field, which should be death, but the program thinks you can survive it:  "F..F", ".O..", "FF.."

Comment: https://tio.run/##K85LzMwp/v8/xr9SsVpPJy21XE8nxu3/fzc9PTcuPX89PS43IBMA

Comment: @Xantix Good catch, my triangular search path had a hole in it. Fixed at the cost of 1 byte.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>283</s> <s>218</s> <s>209</s> 208 bytes

```python
lambda F:f(F)&f(F[::-1])
def f(F):l=F.split();w=len(l[0])+1;i=F.index('O');x,y=i/w,i%w;r=range(len(l));return all('F'in''.join(n)for n in[[l[i][x+abs(i-y):]for i in r],[l[i][max(0,y+x-i):i+x-y+1]for i in r]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVPLboMwELz7K6xUrb2C0DjpE8TVVz6AcCACUleOExHawNdTm6dT5VbVkpf1zrC7Hq1PTfVxVOt2H25bmR52WYq5X1AOD9rEvr9kCaAsL7CJ@TLk3vkkRUUhuIQyV1TGqwQcFgiNCJXlNSURgaB2m1A8XlxxfwnKsEzVPqcdHSAo8@qrVDiVkhJOhCLE@zwKRRUUxxIrLFQcy1gkce2kuzMVywb8xEBCQ7hM3B49pDVduY1TLwX4Qn8ah9m0BNpC5DJjOMSLxcLzPG42MtYs5E0OtyLR4PBbHO7pTAh1edcmbzSeNlMVzY2GP2fyUw9zs9BYbKRZvOeZh/SOjOEz/DJUsZtDVx2i8QacXwXNcc7z@k@avE3tIx51N5ix9wHT5XRCXdLC2GqW74Y@fX8Wndk6cLul0eF917@hKxXY@rYM/C8yTAPYzTxz2QZ8hE@lUBXe0/w71VPfVSfYweeqpAIA7oZXRbaKALQ/)

Takes input as a newlines separated string, and returns `True/False` for `Dead/Alive`

Works by checking each direction(udlr) for `F`ire in by looking outward:

Example:

Input:

```python
FFFFF
.....
..O..
.....
```

Fire checks:

```python
Up:       Down:     Left:     Right:

FFFFF               F             F
 ...                ..           ..
  O         O       ..O         O..
           ...      ..           ..
```

If all directions contain fire you die, otherwise there is an escape.

Edit: Back to taking a string as input, and now only checks for up/right, but also checks the input backwards (giving down/left)

Saved a lot of bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) and [Felipe Nardi Batista](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66418/felipe-nardi-batista)

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63498/discussion-between-mr-xcoder-and-felipe-nardi-batista).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 174 bytes

```
a=>+(t=>g=a=>t--?g(a.map((l,y)=>l.map((c,x)=>(h=v=>[(a[y-1]||[])[x],(a[y+1]||[])[x],a[y][x+1],a[y][x-1],c].includes(v),!c&&h()?p=1:[2,0,1].find(h))))):p)((p=a+'!').length)(a)
```

Input format:

- Array of Array of Integers
- 2 for `F`, 1 for `.`, 0 for `O`

Output:

- Truthy value (1) for survive
- Falsy value (NaN) for die

Try It:

```js
f=a=>+(t=>g=a=>t--?g(a.map((l,y)=>l.map((c,x)=>(h=v=>[(a[y-1]||[])[x],(a[y+1]||[])[x],a[y][x+1],a[y][x-1],c].includes(v),!c&&h()?p=1:[2,0,1].find(h))))):p)((p=a+'!').length)(a)
t=s=>f(s.trim().split('\n').map(x=>x.split('').map(n=>({F:2,'.':1,O:0}[n]))))

console.log(t(`
FFFFF
.....
..O..
.....
`))

console.log(t(`
FFFF
FFFO
FFFF
`))

console.log(t(`
.F....
......
......
.F....
..O...
.FF...
.F....
..FF..
`))

console.log(t(`
...F...F
F.......
........
.F......
....O...
...F....
........
.F....F.
`))

console.log(t(`
FFF
FOF
FFF
`))

console.log(t(`
F.F
.O.
F.F
`))

console.log(t(`
....F
.....
..O..
.....
F....
`))

console.log(t(`
.F....F.
........
........
F..O....
........
.....F..
`))

console.log(t(`
...F...F
F......F
........
.F......
....O...
...F....
........
.F....F.
`))
```

Consider a cellular automaton. There are 3 states for a cell `O` (reachable by people), `F` (catch fired), `.` (nothing just happened). The rule for create next generation is:

```
for each cell:
  me and my 4 neighborhoods,
    if anyone is `F` then result is `F`,
    otherwise, if anyone is `O` then result is `O`
    otherwise, keep state `.`
```

Once there is an cell on edge has `O` state, the people survive. If this not happened in enough amount generation, then the people died.

```
// check for all neighbors:
h=v=>[(a[y-1]||[])[x],(a[y+1]||[])[x],a[y][x+1],a[y][x-1],c].includes(v)
// if me == 'O' and i'm edge (neighbors contain _undefined_), then survive
!c&&h()?p=1
// Otherwise apply the given rule
:[2,0,1].find(h)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 71 bytes

```matlab
@(a)(A=blkdiag(0,a,0))<3||any((bwdist(A>2,'ci')>bwdist(A==2,'ci'))(!A))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNRU8PRNiknOyUzMV3DQCdRx0BT08a4piYxr1JDI6k8JbO4RMPRzkhHPTlTXdMOJmBrCxXR1FB01NT8n5hXrMEVbaigoADDxkhsMJ8LQwgFc@GWQkgbE6/bCLe0MdXsBovFcmn@BwA)

or

[Verify all test cases!](https://tio.run/##3VXLboMwELz7K@gJr4RQsG@ljso/9FZxcAikKIhWxWkVNfl2amEKNhiapJyKtJYZz673MYjXRPCPtBbvB/FydJjj@z76Qo58nh0Syw1SL4FcOmugZkvGUGdx60rlYpiFOw4xF3kyuuLqEBlDtCmrq4rO53H9Eb2wsLEXvSmg4Rlb5jX019oU3FDpBQnORyHzFLp4LrTtzDlEGS@qtBf6QEN9Y4hFTrrkAlPIpE@iO7WNIlhM/xMz1C@dbMVVDf2FQqcG@@eLltY0/ZeaNhRpU6U5Kr2p57B@xBxwxDbFfpvzHV553FsBPNDTiZdHjDef27wSOFoTz01yF9Y/AGMtAvguAqgzxssqRPLwDbtPaSXycueon8q9CyhJiyI7lDjzFAYDpvoqTabCoP4G)

Input format:

- 2D array of integers
- `1` for `.`, `2` for `O` and `3` for `F`

Output:

- `true` and `false`

Explanation:

Explanation:

```matlab
A=blkdiag(0,a,0)    % add a boundary of 0s around the array
A<3                 % return truthy when there is no fire
bwdist(A>2,'ci')    % city block distance transform of binary map of fire
bwdist(A==2,'ci')   % city block distance transform of binary map of your location
any(...)(!A)        % check if there is at least one element on the boundary of 
                    % the fire distance map has its distance greater than 
                    % that of distance map of your location
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 243 bytes

```
^.*O(.|¶)*|(.|¶)*O.*$|(.|¶)*(¶O|O¶)(.|¶)*
O
m`^((.)*) (.*¶(?<-2>.)*(?(2)(?!))O)
$1#$3
m`^((.)*O.*¶(?<-2>.)*(?(2)(?!))) 
$1#
T`p`\O`#| ?O ?
+m`^((.)*)[O ](.*¶(?<-2>.)*(?(2)(?!))F)
$1#$3
+m`^((.)*F.*¶(?<-2>.)*(?(2)(?!)))[O ]
$1#
}T`p`F`#|.?F.?
O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY0xDsIwDEV3n8KoHewgLFFWRDavXtiAKgwMDCCEGMO1eoBeLDSojRiopTjf1pPf8/K63s8pteKMJPYduzj@Jq6eMvWdRRvSOIPBLbREwo6RxPUd@e2q2Q0zeWqY/ILZGOp1VW8KajMgYwZhHx7haKGK6A09LIvhYHiak@gkKbjOWfKZr@idTTqIxKt4sJQQUfOD3HMBlqA/GxuD/mMUPw) Requires the background to be spaces rather than `.`s (or some other regexp-safe character could be used). Explanation:

```
^.*O(.|¶)*|(.|¶)*O.*$|(.|¶)*(¶O|O¶)(.|¶)*
O
```

If there is an `O` on any edge, delete everything else (survival case)

```
m`^((.)*) (.*¶(?<-2>.)*(?(2)(?!))O)
$1#$3
```

Place a `#` in any space above an existing `O`.

```
m`^((.)*O.*¶(?<-2>.)*(?(2)(?!))) 
$1#
```

And a `#` in any space below an existing `O`.

```
T`p`\O`#| ?O ?
```

Change the `#`s to `O`s, and also any space to the left or right of an existing `O`.

```
+m`^((.)*)[O ](.*¶(?<-2>.)*(?(2)(?!))F)
$1#$3
```

Place `#`s above any existing `F`s. These can overwrite `O`s as well as spaces.

```
+m`^((.)*F.*¶(?<-2>.)*(?(2)(?!)))[O ]
$1#
```

Place `#`s below any existing `F`s, also overwriting `O`s as well as spaces.

```
}T`p`F`#|.?F.?
```

Change the `#`s to `F`s, and also any `O` or space to the left or right of an existing `F`. Repeat until the `F`s have consumed everything.

```
O
```

Return `1` for survival, `0` if not.