# Fryer simulator

Tags: code-golf, matrix

Your task is to model the effects of batter on pieces of food. Please add three layers of crust.

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0], // in
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
                   |
                   V
[[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,2],
 [0,0,2,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,2,0],
 [0,0,2,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,2,0,0],
 [0,0,0,2,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,2,1,2,0],
 [0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,2,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0]]
                   |
                   V
[[0,0,3,2,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,2,1,2],
 [0,3,2,1,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,3,2,2,3,2,3],
 [0,3,2,1,1,1,2,3,0,0,0,3,2,1,1,2,3,0],
 [0,0,3,2,1,2,3,0,0,0,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,3],
 [0,0,0,3,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,3,2,1,1,1,2,3],
 [0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,2,2,2,3,0]]
                   |
                   V
[[0,4,3,2,3,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,3,2,1,2], // out
 [4,3,2,1,2,2,3,4,0,0,0,4,3,2,2,3,2,3],
 [4,3,2,1,1,1,2,3,4,0,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4],
 [0,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,0,4,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,3],
 [0,0,4,3,2,3,4,0,0,0,4,3,2,1,1,1,2,3],
 [0,0,0,4,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,2,2,2,3,4]]
```

A little visual aid:

```css
body {
   background-color:#222;
   color:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<pre>
[[<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>], // in
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>]]
                   |
                   V
[[<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>]]
                   |
                   V
[[<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>]]
                   |
                   V
[[<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>], // out
 [<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>],
 [<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>],
 [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>]]
</pre>
```

The input is a boolean matrix representing the fryer: 0 for the oil, 1 for the food.
Your function or program should add the three layers as 2s, 3s, and 4s around the 1s, thus overwriting some of the 0s. Batter sticks horizontally and vertically (but not diagonally) to food of any shape or size, including donuts (food with holes) and crumbles (isolated food "pixels"), and is restricted to the boundaries of the fryer. Earlier layers of batter turn into crust and are not affected by later ones.

In other words, first you should replace all 0s that are in the von-Neumann neighbourhoods of 1s with 2s, then replace all 0s in the von-Neumann neighbourhoods of 2s with 3s, and finally replace all 0s in the von-Neumann neighbourhoods of 3s with 4s. Thus, the numbers 2,3,4 represent a quantity one greater than the Manhattan distance to the nearest 1-cell.

The fryer will be of size at least 3-by-3 and it will contain at least one piece of food. I/O is flexible - use a matrix format suitable for your language. Extra whitespace is allowed, shorter code desirable, loopholes forbidden.

More tests:

```
 [[0,0,1], // in
  [0,0,0],
  [0,1,0]]

 [[3,2,1], // out
  [3,2,2],
  [2,1,2]]

 -

 [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], // in
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
  [0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
  [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]]

 [[3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,3,4,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,2,1], // out
  [2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,2,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,2],
  [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,3],
  [1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4],
  [2,2,3,4,4,3,3,3,4,0,0,0,4,3,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,3,4],
  [3,3,4,4,3,2,2,2,3,4,0,0,4,3,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,3,2,3,4,4],
  [4,4,4,3,2,1,1,1,2,3,4,0,4,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,3,3,2,2,2,3,4,3,3],
  [0,4,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,3,4,0,0,4,3,2,2,2,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,2,2],
  [4,3,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,4,3,3,3,2,3,4,4,3,2,2,3,2,1,1],
  [3,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,3,3,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,1,2],
  [4,3,2,1,2,2,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,3,4,4,3,2,3],
  [0,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,2,3,4,0,0,0,4,3,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,3,4,4,3,4],
  [0,0,4,3,2,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,4,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,3,4,4,3,2,3],
  [0,0,0,4,3,3,4,3,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,3,3,4,3,3,4,4,3,2,1,2],
```

A little visual aid:

```css
body {
   background-color: #222;
   color:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<pre>[[<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>], // in
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>]]

 [[<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>], // out
  [<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>],
  [<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>]]

 -

 [[<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>], // in
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
  [<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
  [<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>]]

 [[<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>], // out
  [<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>],
  [<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>],
  [<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>],
  [<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>],
  [<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>],
  [<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>],
  [<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>],
  [<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>],
  [<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>],
  [<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:gold">0</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:orange">4</span>,<span style="color:chocolate">3</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>,<span style="color:red">1</span>,<span style="color:brown">2</span>],
</pre>
```

---

Thanks @Tschallacka for the visualizations.

Comment: Could you provide a walkthrough example, please? It's not clear to me when or why to use 2, 3 or 4. (I'd VTC as unclear but I have a hammer now and it looks like I'm in a minority)

Comment: @Shaggy My understanding is that the numbers identify the "layer". A 1D example: `000010000` → `000212000` → `003212300` → `043212340`

Comment: Thanks, @georgewatson; it looks like you're right. That's not clear from the spec, though, which mentions that "batter" should only stick to food and earlier layers of batter are *not* affected by later ones. The only way to determine that is to decipher it from the test cases.

Comment: @Shaggy yep, what georgewatson said. I added intermediate steps in the example and a paragraph to describe the algorithm in stricter terms. Please tell me if you think I should change anything to improve clarity.

Comment: @Shaggy I believe the hammer only works for closing as a duplicate. Other close votes work as normal.

Comment: Your next challenge should be a Friar simulator.

Comment: @ngn [***really***](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154821/friar-simulator)? ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: May base part of a workshop on this challenge?

Comment: @Adám i don't know what sort of a workshop you mean, but sure, feel free

Answer (score 11):

## Java 8, <s>271</s> <s>269</s> <s>247</s> <s>210</s> <s>202</s> <s>198</s> <s>193</s> <s>186</s> <s>179</s> <s>177</s> 176 bytes

```java
a->{for(int l=a[0].length,i,t,I,J,n=0;++n<4;)for(i=a.length*l;i-->0;)for(t=4;a[I=i/l][J=i%l]==n&t-->0;)try{a[I-=t-t%3*t>>1][J-=t<2?1-2*t:0]-=a[I][J]<1?~n:0;}finally{continue;}}
```

Java and index-dependent matrices.. Not a good combination for an already verbose language to begin with..

Modifies the input-matrix instead of returning a new one.

-8 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##tVdbb5swFH7fr3CROiWNodyeQklVTZuUSuvD@hjx4CVuR@c6GZiuEaJ/PTPggLmYXKSJlmBz/J3vfD4@Ni/oDenrDaYvq9@7JUFxDL6jkKafAAgpw9ETWmLwkDcBeFuHK7Ac8f5FsAgAGnu8O@P//C9miIVL8AAo8MEO6bP0aR3lpoD4aGEGBsH0mf2CIWRwDu8h9U1vMqE3rjcuDH0kLK6IF@r6zCz7me96aDH3w2sSLO798JIEvk8/s9KCRduUv9V9prNL54rNZha34s0b@9bS7Ss2NQOdu5/z3uDGuv2gU9PLnkKKCNmmyzVlIU2wl2U7r4xik/wkPAoRTBHvK1dj9MiikD4XMZdSMByzEcV/gRAjBdfXYE43CZsW7wFITWhCK4Ny05SbFm8WLdHZRvv6vsFLhlcgwnFCalwH2jJu3rTrJn/HmyXu2Mt/TuF7ztWO8ZyrhrAO@8uVK@6WCsI6CNC8OhDHM9gPt06FqIFMVSBtyv0sBuU8wljqHdCil@qwRk0IWbJjIXpYnMJhUAt1Zpjq1FJLdzKLExfZ2cXCHcR1oQMdcc9/3eK5UWBsOARSmtviblcwjlyULKgGEf7ysiX0t4U1f9Nc1HZF0e0FaF7CWg6kwhU0VQz2LASIXGyr6CqaMoRdAe0Hd1hIGks02yxKIWsnjqxFn7HbmA0ZwqqY2DILp0PVbeSEI6m1n2CrvfHIkjWnWJbZqa5yd@qw6HJoBuPIOZE/qbRwOoHUMssZ1JjUdhpbPSAHWTQXU18otRZ1AvyfnVpZOI8sTurdRlFPlRvTMWWv8nZSjTyrGprV5PRNz0BydtOhlQCHVnQr4dxWonXWc192qhK7Nw9VC8mtMq5zdi@Ou0X67U/4eQPulQVYqPqjEFUchKmxHOVmBR4A5UEZMBj5mgYxv5X94mNgEbxPC@tUMH7cxgy/GuuEGRs@khHKj/wv/JvESFhIjLsoQtvYYOsSd/Q@NiK8IfybZKQBDWraWPgFIJr4rHzO2h5bxMUAPDnK0R0he18ixC7lyMB/EkTiER7fal/WUcTdXWhT7RsKCV5dDIwU05Dt/gE)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->{                            // Method with integer-matrix parameter and no return-type
  for(int l=a[0].length,          //  Amount of columns
      i,t,I,J,                    //  Temp integers
      n=0;++n<4;)                 //  Loop `n` in range [1, 4):
    for(i=a.length*l;i-->0;)      //   Inner loop over the cells:
      for(t=4;a[I=i/l][J=i%l]     //    Set I,J to the current cell
                             ==n& //    If the value of the current cell is the current `n`:
              t-->0;)             //     Loop `t` downwards in the range (4, 0]:
        try{a                     //      Get the cell at a location relative to the current
             [I-=t-t%3*t>>1]      //       If `t` is 3:
                                  //        Take the cell above
                                  //       Else if `t` is 2:
                                  //        Take the cell below
             [J-=t<2?1-2*t:0]     //       Else if `t` is 0:
                                  //        Take the cell left
                                  //       Else if `t` is 1:
                                  //        Take the cell right
              -=a[I][J]<1?        //      And if this cell contains a 0:
                 ~n:0;            //       Fill it with `n+1`
        }finally{continue;}       //      catch and ignore ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions
                                  //      (saves bytes in comparison to manual checking)
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Stencil](https://github.com/abrudz/Stencil): 1 + 14 = 15 bytes

Command-line argument: `3`

Code: `s<×⌈/N:1+⌈/N⋄S`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBLCsIwEN17iuxMUWgmrbURz@DGI4iLgqjQ7sSVUkStCCJewqWewJvkIMb82qauSiCZeXkz896k2Xw5SxZCpOPPg58P/mQEPf3y034qxIby4w7zy53n1y7Pb13PJrx41@HT20YIYl68MEQ@8frQx6F9YagCHPggb4gURyOAQP@XCSJIsQc1W3botJ4foEC2JqoLIvZA@3IIEWVKG42tbspKA1GlsLRRIvJT28TMuGMOc6AgYl2ZpkaUFahgcFbzt4ewmZLGVlFzb4bCGoCSELqqqlrLp44JR4cWWM2XRWbOd7XOktUyFcEP)

`3` repeat the following transformation thrice:

`s` if whether the **s**elf is non-empty

`<` is less than

`×` the signum of

`⌈/N` the maximum of the von neuman**N** neighborhood

`:` then the new value becomes

`1+` one plus

`⌈/N` the maximum of the von neuman**N** neighborhood

`⋄` else

`S` the value stays unmodified (**S**elf)

Comment: Shouldn't this be 15 bytes (14+1 for the argument `3`)? First time seeing *Stencil*, but if I understand correctly it's an extension for *Dyalog APL* to benefit matrices? Also, tiny remark: The capital N at the start of `Neumann` should be bold instead of the small one at the end in your explanation. :)

Comment: Well, newest consensus seems to indicate that various configurations of a single language should be counted as separate languages, but I'll add it

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Stencil *can* be used as a Dyalog APL tool for easy cellular automatons, but it also stands on its own as a golfing language. Indeed, one's code may need modification when moving between tool usage and the golfing language.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No, the bold final *N* is intentional. See [the documentation](https://github.com/abrudz/Stencil#code) that Stencil uses the first and last letters of *moore* and *von neumann* as mnemonics for with and without self, and uses lowercase and uppercase as mnemonics for the count of non-empties and the actual list of elements.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I should also mention that Stencil is just an interface to Dyalog APL's `⌺` built-in (called *Stencil*). See also [its documentation](http://help.dyalog.com/16.0/Content/Language/Primitive%20Operators/Stencil.htm). A whole golfing language built on a single build-in! Actually, I have made two other golfing languages basing on single Dyalog APL built-ins: [QuadR and QuadS](https://github.com/abrudz/quadrs).

Comment: @Adám Requiring a command-line argument is a bit of stretch. What stops me from defining a family of 256^n "languages" and claiming that the first n bytes of my programs are just "configuration"?

Comment: @ngn Nothing. That's basically what [MetaGolfScript](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MetaGolfScript) is about.

Comment: @Adám MetaGolfScript is [considered a loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/5076#5076)

Comment: Actually the newest consensus specifies that the `3` argument shouldn't be counted, but then your language isn't **Stencil** but **Stencil *command-line argument `3`***. (cc @KevinCruijssen) so no, you can't just "count" the argument into your score anymore

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Really? :S Could you link me to the relevant meta-post. And in that case sorry _Adám_, since you indeed originally had *Stencil command-line argument `3`* in your initial version. I can't say I agree with all arguments being ignored in the byte-count. Some default ones ok, but what stops me from inputting the entire or part of my code as argument.. :S In this case I see `3` as something specified in the challenge. It's not asked as input. So I could also add the size of the matrix as argument to reduce bytes (in theory)?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Nvm, [found it..](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends/14339#14339) So it basically counts as a different programming language in that case? Ok, now I better understand it..

Answer (score 8):

## [Stencil](https://github.com/abrudz/Stencil) *+CLA: `3`*, 11 bytes

```apl
s:S⋄+∘×⍨⌈/N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JzUvOzPn/v9gq@FF3i/ajjhmHpz/qXfGop0Pf7///R20TNQwUyIOGmmRrNdDUMCRsvoIhlDRE12pIUCMqhGsl3kaYNkNitSIMMEB3MLrTsNuKNZiIUIQkisWvWJ2EPwwgWpGDglitSLaSYidWv@KOWQPMJIE7SIi2lcTED9T6L7@gJDM/r/i/MQA)

-1 thanks to [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m).
-2 thanks to a suggestion on another answer by [ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn), which led me to convert this from **Stencil** to **Stencil *+CLA: `3`***.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 176 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,i=-2,e=enumerate:a*i or f([[E or int((6*max(len(a)>i>-1<j<len(a[i])and a[i][j]for i,j in((r+1,c),(r-1,c),(r,c+1),(r,c-1))))**.5)for c,E in e(R)]for r,R in e(a)],i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/BboMwDIbvPIWPDg2o2bQdqtJbX4Ar4uBBqhlBQEkq0adnCZ3QpnVbfPDv6Pv/ONPNv4/meVkuRU/DW0tAkovsSepCm@ugLXl9oJRhtHDBqjpHwcYjvqYDzdhrgyROfMrUsTuuU8W1INNCFFVXX6JBdsGEaHdKNkKizT67bHbq3jMlwknT/EVERyPPwQEaS7EmWFneZxK15GBaeJhG68HdXGKhiMv17DwONGHYT8Kcu6lnjyEVYsIc/YHOnW/Z5FZT27PRDkUtkgisD9gDTDb@L92CSiGWPfxdCvbJpn6vjVE/uO0m@ZL5gFDfmEebqH@ZrT4A)

-18 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder
-20 bytes thanks to ovs

Comment: "*When I wake up tomorrow morning and look at this code again I'm probably going to feel very dumb.*" You'd better be, since I outgolfed you in Java. ;P

Comment: @KevinCruijssen what D: not acceptable. must not be beaten by Java :P

Comment: Let's beat Java :c – [196 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY/BboMwDIbvPIWPzpoiot1QOfYFuDIOWQmdKwg0ySR62aszB1S0ad0mS4ntfP9vZ7yFt8E@z@fiZe50/9po0HmLMbQQImmLe1eawtj33jgdTF5VRxgcXLHXE@7VgXbu0BnLGm0bri@701pX/FLHJqxpxS91y1KSFyCLqGQmJFssVybVcu4VzxYRO8kjY2CwFIvMyXKttaiT6305ygni4A@aqR8HF8DffOKggDNWHfnAe45INkiYUj92FJD9IRpO0Y7p1IeGbOqMbjqyxqOo@fcMLPNcDqNjPT5tRqUQcwZ/h4Is2bLfY2PUD27rJF88HxDqG/NoE/Uvs8Un).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder yay thanks :c :D

Comment: @ovs oh nice, ty!

Answer (score 3):

## Fortran 95, <s>309</s> <s>299</s> <s>294</s> <s>287</s> 269 bytes

```fortran
subroutine f(a)
integer::a(:,:),s(2)
integer,allocatable::b(:,:)
s=shape(a)
allocate(b(0:s(1)+1,0:s(2)+1))
do1 k=0,3
do1 i=1,s(1)
do1 j=1,s(2)
b(i,j)=a(i,j)
if(any((/b(i+1,j)==k,b(i-1,j)==k,b(i,j+1)==k,b(i,j-1)==k/)).and.b(i,j)<1.and.k>0)b(i,j)=k+1
1 a(i,j)=b(i,j)
end
```

Fortran is not a golfing language.

- **Edit:** Saved 10 bytes by using weird old-fashioned do loops.
- **Edit 2:** Saved 5 bytes with `any()`
- **Edit 3:** Saved 7 bytes by removing an unnecessary `if`
- **Edit 4:** Saved 18 bytes by shrinking declaration of `s`

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>107</s> 105 bytes

```js
f=(m,k=1)=>k<4?f(m.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>v|[-1,0,1,2].every(d=>(m[y+d%2]||0)[x+~-d%2]^k)?v:k+1)),k+1):m
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(m,k=1)=>k<4?f(m.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>v|[-1,0,1,2].every(d=>(m[y+d%2]||0)[x+~-d%2]^k)?v:k+1)),k+1):m

draw = a => O.innerText += a.map(r => r.join(',')).join('\n')+'\n\n'

draw(f(
 [[0,0,1],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,1,0]]
))

draw(f(
 [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
  [0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
  [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]]
))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

#### Commented

```js
f = (m, k = 1) =>                  // given the input matrix m[] and starting with k = 1
  k < 4 ?                          // if this is not the 4th iteration:
    f(                             //   do a recursive call:
      m.map((r, y) =>              //     for each row r[] at position y in m[]:
        r.map((v, x) =>            //       for each cell v at position x in r[]:
          v |                      //         if v is non-zero
          [-1, 0, 1, 2].every(d => //         or each neighbor cell at (x+dx, y+dy), with:
            (m[y + d % 2] || 0)    //           dy = d % 2 --> [-1, 0, 1, 0]
            [x + ~-d % 2]          //           dx = (d - 1) % 2 --> [0, -1, 0, 1]
            ^ k                    //           is different from k  
          ) ?                      //         then:
            v                      //           let the cell unchanged
          :                        //         else:
            k + 1                  //           set the cell to k + 1
        )                          //       end of inner map()
      ),                           //     end of outer map()
      k + 1                        //     increment k for the next iteration
    )                              //   end of recursive call
  :                                // else:
    m                              //   stop recursion and return m[]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>146</s> 143 bytes

```python
e=enumerate;l=input()
for y,f in e(l):
 for g,h in e(f):x=1+min(abs(y-a)+abs(g-c)for a,b in e(l)for c,d in e(b)if d==1);l[y][g]=x*(x<5)
print l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVPLboMwELzzFRYn3DgSW6kXiI/ptZfeEKqAmIdKDHKNAl9PeZcSXon24PUyo50d1mkhw4S/ll5yYVRV1ZJRxrMrE45kZkwjnmZSw4qfCFQQH0UcMS3GhoLqSkDCtuJjI6dwuEZcc9wfrTg6@FAnwdHDNdAhbk@trx65tFcXRz66UArYjK3CtgKb5i9afnrDSioiLlFcVpqUWxjFDH2KjFWNEcuZh2q9VS5FYQjn9tXpNBtWg/FYKtH54/0sRCIMVzDnu7QsnawHEN0m1pAvxwgFd8ihMqD0BQxMUHOKYAfqT5etKO2Y0BOaE8afngnY13/RLdju0Dky8bPhwibzf@h3/m/37Hmwmzv@1zC7HesbAqubtYoaVefmnVW17kPHHfuxlzt9M/DgbsxMsvAKYMVn/bHeT@9z85R@AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 70 bytes

```
Mod[-MorphologicalTransform[#,#[[;;,2]]~Max~#[[2]]&,i]~Sum~{i,0,3},5]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/DfNz8lWtc3v6ggIz8nPx0onBNSlJhXnJZflButrKMcHW1trWMUG1vnm1hRB@QBmWo6mbF1waW5ddWZOgY6xrU6prFq/wOKMvNKotOiq6sNdPBDQx2DWp1qOBs3RFJliKESLgJXZYBDjSGaKmwuMiRCFcJdtbGx/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>34</s> <s>30</s> 23 bytes ([abrudz/SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

```apl
5|{5⊃,⍵+×⌊.⌊⍨⍵}⌺3 3⍣3∘-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///37Sm2vRRV7POo96t2oenP@rp0gPiR70rgPzaRz27jBWMH/UuNn7UMUP3//9HvXMVfBMz8xTSSvOSSzLz8xQ0ikuTcjOLi4FsTS6uNIVHbRMUiDeRiwtkYkhqcYlCcmJxajHQhEdtEzUMFMiDhppkazXQ1DAkbL6CIZQ0RNdqSFAjKoRrJd5GmDZDYrUiDDBAdzC607DbijWYiFCEJIrFr1idhD8MIFqRg4JYrUi2kmInVr/ijlkDzCSBO0iItpXExA/UCgA)

-4 thanks to [ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72607/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-ngn).

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>93</s> <s>87</s> 84 bytes

```
1
4
3{m`(?<=^(.)*)0(?=4|.*¶(?>(?<-1>.)*)4|(?<=40|^(?(1)_)(?<-1>.)*4.*¶.*))
5
T`1-5`d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFBDsIgFET3/ySfJiVMpDtbLuG6YqILF7ow7uRcHsCLYanQ0Bb7w2rezGcIj8vzej/Be5Cm3etm2ezbnqWohGLTaierz5tNN8g1uiBrFyxauZ4NQxzFhHTwykoIauhgUTf27L3aGNAWVYRVAMNBoljCOCMtJgNDiY4GlTandVk2a7WWEKVIs1WLDhQAgCL9ZcvR7N7ZgyeBZl2K2X@foL4) Based on my answer to [Kill it With Fire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/138068). Edit: Saved <s>6</s> 9 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder. Explanation:

```
1
4
```

Turn all the 1s into 4s.

```
3{
```

Repeat the rest of the program (at most) 3 times.

```
m`(?<=^(.)*)0(?=4|.*¶(?>(?<-1>.)*)4|(?<=40|^(?(1)_)(?<-1>.)*4.*¶.*))
5
```

Change all 0s adjacent to 4s into 5s.

```
T`1-5`d
```

Decrement all digits.

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>100</s> 94 bytes

```
1
3
{m`(?<=^(.)*)0(?=3|.*¶(?>(?<-1>.)*)3|(?<=30|^(?(1)_)(?<-1>.)*3.*¶.*))
4
T`1-4`d`^[^1]+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFBDsIgFET3/xwuoKYNE7q05RLujIiJLlzowriTc/UAXgxLhYa22B9W82Y@Q3heX7fH2TmQpPfdMLVrNKt4wQVTjbRV8emYanu5ROtlab1FCquZYuAnPiLpvVXBOdW0NyhrczH6oHHcbpwTKwNao4KwCKA/iBRzGGag2aRnyNHBIOLmuC7JJq2WEoIUaLJq1oE8AJClv2w@mtw7efAo0KRLNvvvE8QX) Explanation:

```
1
3
```

Turn all the 1s into 3s.

```
{
```

Repeat until the output does not change.

```
m`(?<=^(.)*)0(?=3|.*¶(?>(?<-1>.)*)3|(?<=30|^(?(1)_)(?<-1>.)*3.*¶.*))
4
```

Change all 0s adjacent to 3s into 4s.

```
T`1-4`d`^[^1]+$
```

If there are no 1s, decrement all digits.

Comment: You can save some bytes by using a character like `!` (which can't appear in the input) instead of `(?!)`.

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks, that works for Kill it With Fire too (and I found a separate 2-byte golf while I was there!)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 157 bytes

```
import StdEnv,StdLib
t=transpose
z=zipWith
?n=n+sign n
f[0,h:l]=[?h:f[h:l]]
f[h,0:l]=[h,?h:f l]
f[h:l]=[h:f l]
f l=l
$l=z(z max)(t(map f(t l)))(map f l)
```

```
$o$o$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVSxbsMgEN35CqRmsFUqwRoJZWmGStkydLA8UMfESIAtm1SpP770EhLVTW3Hjk8y3BO8ezxxZDoX1ptyd9A5NkJZr0xV1g5v3W5tPwkMG/WBHHe1sE1VNjlqeauqd@UKtLLcPjdqb7FFMqGkWOqUJ6tiKZPTNAWwIPQMFuQEY33GAnJJseYaLTRvoxYEHOPIRUZUWEYO6ziOQwJTv3WidugJFrlaHTHHCZR8LFhKEIbvYQJ6JWD3axF2@bN@AnZ3@9@4IZhe/bqZzSP4paH9R7gV269gxMQJSzvooAe9Ise96RJ0jZpK8E/BnPojHgzfBDp0kYYNm6lgZisBQQpdKQ82g55clBCIhzR0qv/OpBb7xr@8bfzrlxVGZSEJj8sP)

As a function literal.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 63 bytes

Includes +3 for `0ap`

```
perl -0ape 's/0(?=$a|.{@{-}}$a)/$a+1/seg,$_=reverse while($a+=$|-=/
/)<4'
```

Give the input matrix as a block of digits **without** final newline., e.g.

```
001
000
010
```

for the 3x3 example. The output format is the same, a block of digits without final newline.

You can use a small script like

```
perl -i -0pe 's/\n*$//' <file>
```

to conveniently remove the final newlines from a file if that is hard to do in your favorite editor

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>183</s> <s>158</s> 146 bytes

```ruby
->a{3.times{|n|a.size.times{|i|r=a[i];r.size.times{|j|(r[j]<1&&[i>0?a[i-1][j]:0,a[i+1]&.at(j),j>0?r[j-1]:0,r[j+1]].include?(n+1))?r[j]=n+2:0}}};a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDdisIwEEbv@xShF6WhMWT0Tq0@SDYX0a2Q0EZJW8Rt8uzdWfxZRVeWgfDlO@diGN9vTuOuHCcrPcx4Z5qqHYILmrfmq7r@TfCllkYt/ENtQ@6lVUvIMmlWYo3KBBQ2c8EwF6AyrrvcUmaRoooUEQZEihu3rfvPap27Aij94ap0xXQuYowLHUdftX3dkZLs@FbXNZEJkYK9H2BCsZsH79wHD57cW3PniT8sePJebQb/8n73U0ly6LuWnO/AG30Ygt8fA8GH271xeUpSGi/xw6V0/AY)

Uses the obvious three-loop algorithm. <s>The fact that Ruby allows negative indexing into arrays means that there is no way (that I can see) around making the bounds checks.</s> Reaching beyond the boundary of an array returns `nil`, so only the negative bound checks are necessary. The check for `a[i+1][j]` just needs to use the safe access operator.

I also shaved off a few bytes by using a variable for `a[0]`.

-12 more bytes: Use `.times` instead of `(0...x).map` (in three places).

```ruby
->a{
  3.times{|n|                    # For n from 0 to 2
    a.size.times{|i|             # For each row
      r=a[i];
      r.size.times{|j|           # For each column
        (r[j]<1 && [             # If the current cell is 0, and any of
            i>0 ? a[i-1][j] : 0, #     the cell to the north,
            a[i+1]&.at(j),       #     the cell to the south,
            j>0 ? r[j-1] : 0,    #     the cell to the west,
            r[j+1]               #     or the cell to the east
          ].include?(n+1)        #   are set to the previous value,
        ) ? r[j]=n+2 : 0         # Set this cell to the next value (or 0)
      }
    }
  };
  a                              # Return the modified array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 125 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,n=2,e=enumerate:n//5*a or f([[r[j]or n*any([0,*r][j:j+3]+[0,*c][i:i+3])for j,c in e(zip(*a))]for i,r in e(a)],n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVbLbqMwFN3zFV7ixFK5xt1E4kuQF0yHaIhaJ6JEVfvzGT/wC4yTqLFQ8OXcp6@Pffme/p1Ffbsdm/fu48/fDnVENJT0TS@uH/3YTf1BvLy87jp0HtGxbNuxPXH5Knad@C7biuxG3p4Op33N92r2xtvhMMgZPkrUibyhQaC@/Bku5a7DmCvpQEYj7TAnYg/4pqXiQtD5OqlPZVEWqJX28gNIxUmBUOum2yMGwgrsJCGw2oDBGpiKDh4D@hgVUqXNSE2ofGr55r8zLaHSKDUmmZ1qMAtgRiKfGAgabKBepiU2SG9zDQNv0TtaOnZewrRZIhVq4@a8wMSvOASK9hVccbQLI9YmzKspirGDHmmdzUV7eLFybQb3/cx9tGhEqw53leNRpXr3vmerCs@oh7sFtrZYfpvBvR2aBQbSjdyT4eVr4tXD8jyqnuAheL5tElltcArkK189F8Fvej7cmSyLZDOh1fM/s4Rht3DOQEhq1HGjlto9s20g5jAIGJNZmvLMaEZKOR4z2gbv7EW0vfZsvUe0G2QTkXlI8LFi5D2o5SbFw1w076D2FL0GsgVNe3VwEdDl4UIX6pWrB40SnPGexcPyxMsYlrR2Y@MMXPdAWFIaRZHMPXeehR0SnJfVIqvUSZzxHm8Mmjzxa4dwyaqjrsAHaQOhsf@8vk@okdczeYfCWqYuVOP5C6nLlPlusOp3GQcxlfKrgeopKq2VRt3B8O0/)

Adaptation of my answer to [Calculate COVID spread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/214463/calculate-covid-spread)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 217 bytes

```c
for(w=2;w<=4;w++)for(y=0;y<H;y++)for(x=0;x<W;x++){if(o[y][x].v[w%2])continue;if(o[y][x].v[!(w%2)]){o[y][x].v[w%2]=o[y][x].v[!(w%2)];continue;}for(z=0;z<8;z++)if(o[y][x].a[z]&&o[y][x].a[z]->v[!(w%2)])o[y][x].v[w%2]=w;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVRtU6MwEP6c/Io9nVawqIC9OzWgX/sP@gGZmw5tlbkedSpKaeW39zYJbymg7V2ZacjuPs@zWXYTXDwFwe40jILF23QGzms8DZeXz/eUnk5n8zCawZjYt@VmRKwhpXH6MkMDvMartyCGYLZY/HqFLSWq4Xzi3fiMEkrCKIZ3z8ZNJp0xo5Qb/0zCSOMvk9VTYEDwPFkhbPX07vk6J@SuhMl1na9pvm6QQ7yEnjX0PfvWB5djyNY0/u2xMuN/4KaEW1/rGFb@b7XBrS/B6qPAD1cuoNYx8IrEbEt@P8129c7SHRBYs3acvTW9z2tSwevlORS@p36MdufZu7@82d423WU6Sv3IgUE4JZmYcTnXsPRGvjcWo4g/M8OfcM@XKy1Fq8kgBQdGuAwGYsaFay1da3SNcSlcYr4XYfQb3Rp3amO4AEuHB7DgDkwdPkDjfNqosNvCzu8GRM81Ae5zl@AjSy/1vbV/OfGGPMm@3MMALH5VlQHCgEHXtSAZkO0x203mHwVIsBRAUjNgkPUFs@vCdZP65x61mnjdiMFmQ4K0JGIfUofvrUfKaE5ZJPguNautOGVYZcDbZcc/eOLaLHHcIUvwW4vmcE2WOiOW5vs17tfOmPFe2GJRKs6kZ/t6sIziMHqbMcX1TUOn7utbNdptRLASn3GxDYptnBu2QbEa4cTb@P1@fXdxX4nsaSQs25Grc9nqCR7bZpCA48IQV@TNO10ZglTaPx0B0jw8lNk3A4rscjBRocrHKWohA1XOrGoXUSCZ3AaTu8ElT1uR5uWBfh@6yiUBzXySopXOryhtL5E4y8sKL4O5dvIY9wLvxED3A5zhcwdn3pnOSTrvEi5QwHvTXoBopWMf1O2d0sAGv3kG/Aa5d2HMRX0hapSiJXXwGCG1lpbho/3wjGa7vw)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c) page for any golfing tricks!

Comment: am I wrong to post util code between header and footer?

Comment: Ah, good point. Our site rules on I/O are that you can't assume the input is already stored in a variable, and that you have to include the initialisation of variables in your byte count. For C, answers generally take the form of a function, which you can take input as a function parameter (e.g. `f(o)`). You don't have to count the code required to *run* the function (e.g. the `int main { ... }`). I'm not very familiar with C, so I'm not sure what the code in the header/footer is doing, but  if it is part of the task, rather than the I/O, you should count it in your code

Comment: For example, see [this](https://tio.run/##VVDRbsIwDHznK6xKSG3jiqbQQsm8PUz7isEDCumIpoWq4aEa6n69c6GwESmRc3c@@ayTD637XiurauVVFbroXB2bUFOKlmryJNGRi5MfN8uUSxJlyRJlcf0yUELUKNdWyEgL8ujJJkysU@VIq6637gRfO@vCaHKeAJ8BMG1t9Mns37dAcJaY4RwLLFFKlDlmDCwwW@G8wEWGiwLzHIsclykuV1hKLFmZ5p26@OnDron1wehP07DfYBhs2rds05avfPMA4f9/Hox9HBHCYRjr9qbltlSN5RN4@22OVXgbM5qNQHxHFAhxUUdwjXWL5tjpaiNAqgfKMzVs9xE1jN73cenc/gnqhiVVGEz3kDwDv1O/cZzIIXiEW2pPZLajbTfp@l8) C submission, which includes the actual running of the function in the footer

Comment: Usually submissions are full functions or full programs. Suggest `~w&1` instead of `!(w%2)`

Comment: [172](https://tio.run/##jZNNb8IwDIbv/IrCBGpoOjUFBtQErr3v0EOWQ1VgqrSVCRj9Evx1ln6kLTAESlXZ8ePXsaN4@qfnnV@Wq7UfrBRHMact6dgKGbZ2@@2vt1feU2n0XTbh4Ad75cBMDscNszlzOIQ4wjG1sV/4NE2ZOeGUHHEqPoKNB4tgUv5JzpOH9MUSOU/rY6n@TFade83XOjdVGpyse1@9pKqcqtrDmV3nNjt8MrdR1fj35PenLyuz8pqZOc6MI3y7fqAmKF1vtirEug4osyLqQCSc/obFnEX89UArixFO/cJB0czRyUKVMZcNeQ7qpwjpc5cNCleLLAPHM/uSfcuDGhHhHCYSxoVsv8GOJVsqS1ItdgvIvCw@qvUtwzLgnHUWUhPC2QhCTcs7Fc/gtm3kr9V23XDYNXm2lTSGcAp7hKNLhiaw@tqtlEwqoRNIMqm6h4T3ek1Pn5cyiyuZUB4WNE1MDX624gmv1U7X@wg62J6LnhbDoTUdoPLU7ZpgHRwvBqY1JQjEGAFVoWXX6@C6Uru8W00THsfOPKpU4Xj@Aw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")