# The Game of Cat And Mice | With Matrices

Tags: code-golf, math, array, grid, matrix

## Challenge

This coding challenge is to figure out how many rounds the cat can live.
In a \$4\times4\$ matrix, there are a number of mice and exactly 1 cat.
Example:
$$
\begin{array}
{|r|r|}\hline
 &  &  & ⬜ \\
\hline
⬜ &  & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
\hline
⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ &  \\
\hline
 &  &  &  \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

But in each square of the matrix, like a house, up to 5 mice can live in it.
I indicate it with a number in front of the mouse.
There are also squares where there are no mice => Indicated with a blank square.
Example:
$$
\begin{array}
{|r|r|}\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & ⬜ \\
\hline
⬜ & 5 & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
\hline
⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & 2 \\
\hline
1 & 4 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

## About the Cat and Mouse

The cat can, and must, move up, down, left, right and diagonal, **1 step** at a time.
Take into note, that the cat can only eat 1 mouse per round.
The cat will always eat a mouse, because it is always hungry.

The cat prefers the house with the most mice in it, although it knows it can eat just one at a time (don't ask me why).
After the cat has eaten a mouse, the number of mice in the house will of course decrease.
After the cat has eaten a mouse, the cat lives in the home of the eaten mouse, possibly with other mice for the remainder of the round.

In the starting position, the cat can only live where there is no mice.
But even after the first round, of course the cat must live in a house of the mice.

This goes on and on, till:

## Game End

These are the scenarios, when the game ends:

- When there are no more mice around the cat to eat anymore.
  => The cat will starve. (Note the cat cannot eat another mouse in the current house since it must move on, so can end up starving while residing with mice - like in example 5)
- When at least 2 of the houses, the cat **can visit**, has the highest and same number of mice.
  => The cat will die of frustration.

## Rules

- The Input must be a list, or an array, or some datatype that can store the number of mice in the house, and where the cat is.
- Where there is no mice, you can indicate it with just \$0\$
- If you use an array, it could be 1 dimensional, but also 2 dimensional.
- The output must be an integer, the number of rounds the cat did survive.
- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply, of course.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.

Good luck!

Note: In the above matrix I showed, the output must be \$3\$.
=> Death because: the cat can't decide in which house of mice to eat.

### Example

#### Example 1

- Starting state:
  $$
  \begin{array}
  {|r|r|}\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & 5 & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & 2 \\
  \hline
  1 & 4 & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$
- After 1 round:
  $$
  \begin{array}
  {|r|r|}\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & 4\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & 2 \\
  \hline
  1 & 4 & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$
- After 2 rounds:
  $$
  \begin{array}
  {|r|r|}\hline
  1 & 2 & 2\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & 4 & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & 2 \\
  \hline
  1 & 4 & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$
- After 3 rounds:
  $$
  \begin{array}
  {|r|r|}\hline
  1 & 2 & 2 & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & 3\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & 2 \\
  \hline
  1 & 4 & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$
- 4<sup>th</sup> Round: **Death of frustration**
  $$
  \begin{array}
  {|r|r|}\hline
  1 & \underbrace{2} & \underbrace{2} & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & 3\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & 2 \\
  \hline
  1 & 4 & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$

So it just survived 3 rounds.

#### Example 2

- Starting Stage
  $$
  \begin{array}
  {|r|r|}\hline
  1 & 5 & 1 & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & 5 & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & 2 \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & 1 \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$
- End Stage: 1 Round
  $$
  \begin{array}
  {|r|r|}\hline
  1 & 5 & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & 5 & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & 2 \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & 1 \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$

#### Example 3

- Starting Stage
  $$
  \begin{array}
  {|r|r|}\hline
  1 & 5 & 1 & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & 5 & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  2 & ⬜ & 1 & 4 \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$
- End Stage: 7 Rounds
  $$
  \begin{array}
  {|r|r|}\hline
  1 & 2 & 1 & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & 1\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  2 & ⬜ & 1 & 4 \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$

#### Example 4

- Starting Stage
  $$
  \begin{array}
  {|r|r|}\hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & 1 & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & 2 \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$
- End Stage: 5 Rounds
  $$
  \begin{array}
  {|r|r|}\hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$

#### Example 5

- Starting Stage
  $$
  \begin{array}
  {|r|r|}\hline
  ⬜ & 3 & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & 2 & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & 1 & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$
- End Stage: 4 Rounds
  $$
  \begin{array}
  {|r|r|}\hline
  ⬜ & 1\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & 1 & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ & ⬜ \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$
  Good luck again!

Comment: Thanks for using the sandbox, but just so you know, typically you should leave posts there for about two days in order to make sure you've really ironed out any potential issues

Comment: @pxeger ok. shall I delete the post and leave it in the sandbox then?

Comment: I think there are a few things that are still unclear about the challenge. 1) After round 1 in your example, there are 2 houses with 4 mice in it. Should the game not end right then? Why does it prefer a house with 3 mice instead of the ones with 4? 2) Can the cat pass through houses without eating any mice in them? 3) Does the distance between the cat and the house with most mice matter? If it takes 2 or 3 steps for the cat to reach there and eat a mouse, will that be counted as a single round?

Comment: @ManishKundu 1) No, the cat dies only when there are houses which it can reach has mice with the same number. 2) No, it's hungry always. 3) Yes it can only eat mice in the houses which is 1 step near. I'll include it in the post. Thanks.

Comment: @math I don't think that's necessary, it will just create churn, but just for in future

Comment: Regarding sandboxing period, my rule of thumb is a week, plus explicitly asking for feedback in the chat a couple times.

Comment: Would suggest adding a few more examples

Comment: @ManishKundu Ok, working on it. I'll add the starting stage and the end stage.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/176251/58563)

Comment: Can we just store the number of mice in the matrix / list and take the coordinates (x,y) of the cat separately?

Comment: @Arnauld Yes you can.

Comment: Will the cat die if two neighbor cells have same number of mice but not the greatest ones? For example, [1, 4, 1; 0, Cat, 0; 0, 0, 0]. Two 1s are where cat **can visit**, and have same number of mice. But cat should / would choice the 4 in this turn without any confusing.

Comment: @tsh The cat will go to the 4, it won't bother to choose one of the 1's.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what "When at least 2 of the houses, the cat can visit, has the same number of mice." means. Maybe you can modify it to clarify such situation.

Comment: @tsh ok, modifieng.

Comment: Can we take the matrix as a dictionary with positions as keys and number of mice as values?  Or similar?

Comment: "*After the cat has eaten a mouse, the cat lives in the home of the eaten mouse, possibly with other mice*" seems to contradict the examples, which appear to imply it must move every round. (e.g.: in example 1 under "After 2 rounds" the cat moves, even though there are still 4 mice which it could eat). Did I miss a stipulation that the cat must always move? Furthermore, if the cat reaches a house with >1 mice, eating 1 that day but is now surrounded by empty houses, does it then die of starvation even though there are mice in the house it is in? (It looks like it from the "Game End" section.)

Comment: @JonathanAllan As the cat can only eat mice which is 1 up, down, left... it can't eat mice which is in it's current square. And your second point, the cat will starve when there is no more mice in the houses which it *can* reach.

Comment: Thanks @math, I made an edit to clarify this, please review it by clicking the "edited" link below the post.

Comment: "(note that the cat." Hum OK, noted.. *stares at the empty wall in confuse thoughts about a bracket that was never closed, a nightmare for all us coders - then looks at the cat sleeping on his lap* Purr? Yes noted that too! ;)

Comment: @Kaddath I committed an unforgivable sin in maths!

Comment: @Kaddath oops (#^.^#), sorry!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <sup><s>167</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>159</s></sup> 155 bytes

Saved <s>2</s> 5 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!
Saved 4 bytes thanks to [Delfad0r](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/82619/delfad0r)!!!

```python
def f(a,c,r=0):
 while(l:=sorted([[z,-a.get(c+z,0)]*2for x in(1,1j,1+1j,1-1j)for z in(x,-x)],key=list.pop))[0][1]<l[1][1]:r+=1;c+=l[0][0];a[c]-=1
 return r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJRb6MwDH7nV1h9IRlmItBqJ7rsjzB0QmlYYYiikOkoVX97Lw70tjvt4RBKnM9fPtuxh7M9nvrsx2But4OuoWYVKjQy4XkAv45Np1mXy/FkrD6wopgxrh7ftGUqmjHh5UNanwxM0PRMoGhRRLTEouWEz4RPGE@8xHd9ll0z2sfhNHBeJGUhyufOLe7PTSTFXkWyIzwp91WhyliKAIy2H6YH43MbKDfK6x4TTNW/abYlzIPnv8BZTtH5QbT7wTS9ZRt42RRKyrmMRmvYUgdVwaMNPK8u1P1BhiF3gsstZy1GGH/5HMHq0f6sQAIL4JLkAkG0eYqQtnnmbPcQ@c6dosyjGREyAre0O5I/O6e44heBnRcQ3wj8D9fHX8X9xe@Deb74h3qnpAvls4o/ms6xlq2obAIxa9HvKaY80NOglRsU8mYo8Al3uOWBOmr1rg2h4etH@rRVIYK3ROYekhpHQ6epeXMzsOVlEZZQCHdZ32ZYx8Cbo9OsP49Lo@oQ4he4jFe4rJELLeVYXl/7kN9@Aw)

Inputs a dictionary mapping each house in the array (represented by a complex number) to the number of mice in that house along with the position of the cat as a complex number.
Return the number of rounds before the cat "dies" (no cats or mice where harmed in this answer, they're all professional actors just playing their parts).

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##jVLBboMwDL3zFb6RDFMRaLWJKvsRhiaUhhaGAIVMa1f127s4Wbdp2mGn@D2/PNtx5pM9TGPxMJvrdadbaFmDCo3MeBnB26EbNBtKuUzG6h2rqmNywma115aphOKM13d5Oxk4QjeyVGCGghM@Bdxj1qPoedeCk9f4ok9y6Ba7mqeZ8yoVdSXqx6FKcwpKk0ixVYkcfCart02l6lSKCIy2r2YE45ucWUPtUR0zvblKYJpxr9maWE@rafhNw2y60bLQvbuWOM0dNchRjzsZQ8yjm4hHVi/2uQEJLIJzVgoE0Zc5Qt6XhYsThzYOJYVnCxIURK7pdCKPXVJc8IfBxhuIPwz@o/X1P839xb@Leb34Jb1J8iD5nuLL0yU@x1Y0NpFY9OjPHHMe6eOslfsGlC1Q4D1ucM0jddDqRRti46fX/H6tYgQficI9KW2DvpSmfbx3MwsvixBKIdxsw5L8bn2wOEf/GwMMi2ljBYttjF2gsXBWF0gf4bxcXBjaqLSUS315GmN@/QA) by using `list.pop` as a key function.

Comment: @ovs Nice one, was wondering if there's a better key function - thanks! :D

Comment: And [161 bytes](https://tio.run/##jVJRj4IwDH7nV/SNTYphoPGCmX8EyYXMqSABMmbEM/x2bxt6dzE@XLKk7ddvX9t13VUf2yb56NT9vpN72JMCBSoe0dSDy7GsJalT3rdKyx3JsgGL@UFqIoIBI5rP4n2rYICyISFDhiGr0B5nAxeEFjUxzfEkr7wuez3v2o7SLGR5xvJNnYWxdVIVcLYWAa9dJsrXRSbykDMPlNRn1YByHXaksL3Zwqq9mNKgiuYgycKiDhZt/QpDp8pGk6l5cy0wnJnpL6Iomx33wafek0Q9LXv9WQAH4sEtShkCq9IYIa7SxPhmsHRpoiBxaGIJiQUX1hqSi02SjfhHYOkE2BuB/3Bd/Ye4u/i@mOOzF@qTEk@U3yl@NE3iMbawY1sQkwqdjTGmnhw6KcwfsNnEbHqFS1xQTxylOEllUX97jlcL4SM4jyXmSe027H@Sdh9fZUeml0WYSiE8Zaclud06pzeK7itO4bSYvS@g14XSPRQabmKEcAO3fjTu1EYmOe/zcdv49P4N) by enumerating all values of `x+y`.

Comment: @ovs Very nice - thanks! :D

Comment: [-4 bytes](https://tio.run/##jVJRb6MwDH7nV1h9IRlmItBqJ7rsjzB0QmlYYYiikOkoVX97Lw70djvt4RBKnM9fPtuxh7M9nvrsx2But4OuoWYVKjQy4XkAv45Np1mXy/FkrD6wopgxrh7ftGUqmjHh5UNanwxM0PRMoGhRRLTEouWEz4RPGE@8xHd9ll0z2sfhNHBeJGUhyufOLe7PTSTFXkWyIzwp91WhyliKAIy2H6YH43MbKDfK6x4TTNW/abYlzIPnL@Asp@j8INr9YJresg28bAol5VxGozVsqYOq4NEGnlcX6v4gQwi5U1yuOWsxwvjr5zhWj/ZnBRJYAJckFwiizVOEtM0zZ7vHyHfuFGUezYiQEbil3ZH82TnFFf8S2HkB8Y3A/3B9/FXcX/w@mOeLf6h3SrpQPqv4o@kca9mKyiYQsxb9nmLKAz0NWrlhIW@GAp9wh1seqKNW79oQGr5@pE9bFSJ4S2TuIal5NHiaGjg3A1teFmEJhXCX9a2GdRS8OTrN@vO49KoOIX6By3iFyxq50FKO5fW1D/ntNw). Also, nice footer :)

Comment: @Delfad0r Sweet, was trying to reduce that huge tuple - thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>122 113 112</s>  111 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @l4m2*

Expects `(mice_array)(cat_x, cat_y)`.

```javascript
m=>g=(x,y)=>!m.reduce((o,v,n)=>6>>(n%4-x)**2+((n>>2)-y)**2&1?v>h?!(p=n,h=v):o|v==h:o,h=0)&&1+g(p&3,p>>2,m[p]--)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY/BbsIwDIbvfQo4rLKpg5IUdkBKeBDEAZXSbqJJBFsEEu9eXKi2IjGkyZfflv/Pvz83cXMsDh/hSzi/LdudaRtjKwMnOqOx42Z6KLffRQngKZLj0bu14N5m4oSTic4AnLUaxbnrUrWMtl6OIRhHtYm48JdoTL3w3ElMU5VVENKcAnuoWYW1ENgW3h39vpzufQXZDlbJaKRIU06SWEqas@hlV5puCzNSpJI1giaNmCRPKXNeekG5yxuFr/2Lojsjh@gpfRb1Z5b7qZ6ihlnYOojVUeQLSv5r1Y@UwXPyh9JeAQ)

#### Commented

This is a bit similar to [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177545/58563) to [my own challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/176251/58563).

```javascript
m =>                   // m[] = flat array of mice
g =                    // g is a recursive function taking
(x, y) =>              // the position (x, y) of the cat
!m.reduce((o, v, n) => // for each value v at position n in m[]:
  6 >>                 //   bitmask of valid squared distances
  (n % 4 - x) ** 2 +   //   compute (prev_x - x)²
  ((n >> 2) - y) ** 2  //   + (prev_y - y)²
  & 1 ?                //   if it's either 1 or 2:
    v > h ?            //     if v is greater than the highest value h:
      !(p = n, h = v)  //       copy n to p and v to h, clear o
    :                  //     else:
      o | v == h       //       set o if v = h (frustrated cat!)
  :                    //   else:
    o,                 //     leave o unchanged
  h = 0                //   start with o = h = 0
)                      // end of reduce()
&&                     // if it's falsy:
  1 +                  //   increment the final result
  g(                   //   and do a recursive call:
    p & 3,             //     new x
    p >> 2,            //     new y
    m[p]--             //     decrement m[p]
  )                    //   end of recursive call
```

Comment: Wow. looks good.

Comment: Seems you don't use that no valid move can also be treated as frustraction as every way is 0

Comment: I mean [this](https://tio.run/##lY7NCsIwEITvfQo9WHZ1I03aeihsfBDxUPxpFfODSlAQX72m2qMIspcZmPl2jnWoL5vzwV@Fddtdt@fOsG4YbnRH1mZuag@OIZCNdqE12EkhbjidqhmA1VqhuPculUvHQbfLMXi21HLAyj0Cc1tl0WX4GLs0Fc8GfJqTj0UyK78WAruNsxd32s1ProE9rJLRSJKinDKKMqMyikH2p@gdKEiSTNYIihRi8o1RxsgPxke@GfHXHwzV1@KAgTHskP2O7gU)

Comment: It crashes for empty init board

Comment: @l4m2 Yup. Rolled back.

Comment: [Output false for 0](https://tio.run/##lY/PDoIwDMbvPAUeJK10hk3xQLLxIMSDQQSNbIt/Fk18dxxKjAc1Mb18bdrf93W3cqtjedjaE9NmXXUb2bVS1RIudEWpRu30UK3PZQVgyJH2o4VSoMdzdsHJRMQAWimB7Np3Ec@davIRWKmpkQ4zc3NSNpnxXYJRxOMabDQj62@oLeySMexKo49mX033poYNFEEYchI0o4S8TCj1YpB9CXoszIkTD5YIggRiEHyCpH7nB@QpHxBv9g9E9Hc@wgAZkvBvSZ5Gb/Zf5Oud7g4)

Comment: Point is 0/0 is not 1

Comment: @l4m2 Oh, I see. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>137</s></sup> 134 bytes

```hs
(x,y)!l|d<-[a|a@((i,j),k)<-l,((x-i)^2+(y-j)^2-2)^2<2],m<-foldr(max.snd)1d,[i]<-[i|(i,k)<-d,k==m]=1+i!((i,m-1):[a|a<-l,fst a/=i])|0<1=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDBbsMgDIbvfQpa9QAqZIGmm1SFapfd9gZRpiBBNxqSVCTa0invnpm03bpNlm1kPv82vKm2NM6NI@7piczdoFOWqUE9YmzpgdCSpMxRjHtmyYtY4RM7QGYCQipyWqVs3zjtcaX6qK014ZpmNgcNO4BA6Na0lLLKJV/ZeRCtGCfbMCII79sOqTtpczLEKZfxWClbS93MEOq3p61PGSgfkTdKRx@N1220t64zHhd10z05UxULynYLki53r6Z7trUh0OpMh5zMYFpRNbpIqC20fS@S8JzrWp/2mMVRlC87VRrE75HPofPobd0tL38hpVOwn4d6WGsUSFDEkUBrFINtpng2AfUEnCO2Q@sZAIHcgP8nz3ki@YyfNX@TYrpPLtxEPsziQP7o8JsT/9YGcnMl138m3vbEgUy@AA)

The function `(!)` takes as input the position of the cat `(x,y)` and a list with one `((i,j),k)` entry for each house, where house at position `(i,j)` as `k` mice (possibly zero).

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 39 bytes

```
Ｅ⁴ＳＪＮＮＷ⁼№ＫＭ⌈ＫＭ¹«⊞υωＭ✳⁻³⌕ＫＭ⌈ＫＭＰＩ⊖ＫＫ»⎚ＩＬυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9PSwMxEMXPm0@R4wRWSFtvPW4rKI0s6BeI69AN5s82m2kF8bPHZKvo0csw8/jN471h1HEI2ubcR@MTKD3Bbcvv/UTpKRXpCEKILXsgNz0HWPRHci8YQXxjP2ehLqOxyGF/Im1n6AIVxx7xTYUQsT4o/W4cub@iKPJKCP7Bmp7mEajll2LVqHBG2JmIQzLBgzKeZti0/M7413@YLqkbRTaZaWnW6TnBDoeIDn3CqwdcuU/WWdSlw5b1v/AB/TGVQBXJWW6kZHJdh1zVUTe2zjdn@wU) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes as input a list of 4 strings of digits, followed by the 0-indexed across and down coordinates. Explanation:

```
Ｅ⁴Ｓ
```

Print the mouse counts to the canvas.

```
ＪＮＮ
```

Move to the cat's starting position.

```
Ｗ⁼№ＫＭ⌈ＫＭ¹«
```

Repeat while the cat has a unique choice of best move.

```
⊞υω
```

Track the number of moves.

```
Ｍ✳⁻³⌕ＫＭ⌈ＫＭ
```

Actually make that move. (Annoyingly the `Peek` and the `Direction` directions don't match up with each other...)

```
ＰＩ⊖ＫＫ
```

Decrement the number of mice at the new position.

```
»⎚ＩＬυ
```

Clear the canvas and output the number of moves taken.