# Virus vs Antidotes code golf

Tags: code-golf

There is a rectangular 2D array containing viruses denoted by 'v', antidote1 denoted by 'a', and antidote2 denoted by 'b' (there are no values other than 'v', 'a' and 'b').

Antidote1 can kill neighboring viruses in horizontal and vertical directions only, but antidote2 can kill neighboring(if any) viruses in horizontal, vertical and diagonal directions.

Once the antidotes are activated, how many viruses will remain at the end?

#### Examples:

Input:

```
vv
vv
```

Output: 4

Input:

```
av
vv
```

Output: 1

Input:

```
vvv
vbv
vvv
```

Output: 0

Input:

```
bvb
bav
vab
vvv
vvb
vvv
vvv
bva
vav
```

Output: 3

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance that doesn't matter.

Comment: I appreciate your edits @Grimy - Also nice challenge :)

Comment: @manatwork, there are no values other that "v", "a" and "b".

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, it is not irregular shaped.

Comment: May we take 3 (distinct) arbitrary values instead of "v", "a", and "b"?

Comment: do the anti-viruses wrap around (ie, "a" in bottom row would remove a "v" in top row)?

Comment: Just a kindly reminder: the challenge is likely to remain closed until unclear points have been clarified. The corresponding answers must be integrated in the body of the challenge (users are not supposed to read the comments, which may later be removed anyway). Also, we have a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/58563) to help fixing a question before it is posted to the main site. Enjoy your stay!

Comment: @Brian Test case #4 implies no (horizontal) wrap.

Comment: @Kiara Dan I would advise not allowing any 3 distinct values, as it keeps some character in the challenge, as well as possible forced cleverness with code points of the letters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 126 bytes

```python
j=''.join
g=lambda*s:eval('j(s)'+4*'.replace("%s%s","%s%s")'%(*'vbbbbvbbavacvaca',))
f=lambda x:j(map(g,*map(g,x))).count('v')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU/LDoIwELz3KxoM2W4lRCMnE77EeNgiooRXBBv9eiyisdSg06bbbWcms829O9XVpu/zGCDM63PFsrigUh1ItttUUyEgFy3CMpIQXtKmoCQVnt/6rReMBcEXErQyMAdpSswmCBDZ8WXFb9tclNSILJBjuSFimNTXqhOgAfvmcjbXo9h5WnsB428M7R6R8wWP2IdEc6Q1s50clnJVo2zBV79UNKeyA5nRJyzlqkh9uUz7f//TXmn6Sjmm2tiplB7gzk30fCbHcViWT/8A)

-2 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

## Explanation

Replaces all 'v' to 'b' if found next to 'b'. Next, replaces all 'v' to 'c' if found next to 'a'. A second iteration with the transposed version of the array clears all vertical and diagonal viruses. Finally, it will return the remaining number of 'v's.

---

Without eval:

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 133 bytes

```python
j=''.join
g=lambda*s,r=str.replace:r(r(r(r(j(s),'vb','bb'),'bv','bb'),'av','ac'),'va','ca')
f=lambda x:j(map(g,*map(g,x))).count('v')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU/LDoIwELz3Kxo9bEsaotGTCV9iPOzik/BKwY1@PVLxASXo7qEz7cxkWt7rc5GvmiaJAMKkuOTiFKWY0R6Dytioqm1oD2WK8WFjVbeJqrQBJjBABC0k/kB0EGMHGVsYI2hxfCXK2yZRGZbqZILuuGmtw7i45rUCBt2U9tLCo9rOmGdGyPc4utNayrlci68Ip0RL0U/yVOS7OttcLn65cMrVL0RMAxX5LqRRypD/ex9yYhy17Fqt@q2I3fj/Rnxeo5fotpfTPAA)

Comment: You can remove the space after `y>1else`. Nice approach though. At first I wasn't sure how this deals with the diagonal `b`, but that seems to work just fine due to your replacements. :) +1 from me.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks! The diagonals are taken care of by replacing 'v' with 'a' if they are next to 'b'. In the second iteration, the adjacent 'v's are then removed.

Comment: For the following input, output should be 3, but its returning 4 :bvb
bav
vab
vvv
vvb
vvv
vvv
bva
vav

Comment: @KiaraDan Ah, in that case my 05AB1E answer has the same issue, being a port of this. I'll delete my answer for now. The incorrect part is the bottom section btw: `vvv bva vav`. It will become `avc bca cac`, so fails to replace the `v` from the diagonal connection with `b`.

Comment: @KiaraDan Thanks! I fixed it with an additional replacement sequence.

Comment: [164 bytes by using `j=''.join` in your fixed version](https://tio.run/##hVHRioMwEHz3KxZLya4Vaa/lHo76Jcc97HqRU6wGbYPez3sJclQtvZtA2CEzwyQxw/WrqY/jWKZKJWVT1EGeVnyRT4Y@HtL9W44XNljG34XBCLXlClWndvgahUmrTcWZRrXtVOw3CmmL0d2gmG0mkrGIZSexGfNERBRRTJQ3LXRQ1NCT48PuQEUOw/lFV52GEntKsuZWX1FZRaNpCzfm@B5aG8YB/MLTDyKADZyCu4ifiQ7BPGmlkrVrsm1g/5eLn7nmhcTKQiVrF8tDypL/d77k7p0fWk6tjvNWYj3W93Zf58GrRL9mOeMP)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Found an even shorter one, but your suggestion saves another byte!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7), 108 bytes

Takes input as a matrix of characters.

```javascript
f=m=>(g=(y,X,V)=>m.map(r=>r.map((v,x)=>V?v>f&V>'a'>(x-X)**2+y*y-2?r[x]=n--:0:v<f?g(-y,x,v):n++)|y++))(n=0)|n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY7NDoIwEITvPAUn2UJbUTkRW96CmBAOrQLRQCFgGpr47viTGMGo4eBls7M782VOQotu3x6bM1H1IRuGnFWMQ8HA4B2OEeMVrUQDLePtYwGN@9s1jjTPFzF3hMOhJzvkumvPuIasozbpU6YICf1Qb/OoAGJwjzUKleehi7kNBIr56KKGfa26usxoWReQQ2Ivl3Zg2XZCKXW0dlI8FlaKkPUhsXqaxNyE/zJNInIK@EEIvhDEbMLm6ZJ/IMhRRk4JQr7zRurXb6ykFu8d762GKw)

*Similar to my original answer, but doing `V>'a'>(x-X)**2+y*y-2` is actually 1 byte shorter than using the hexa trick described below. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯*

---

## JavaScript (ES7), 109 bytes

Takes input as a matrix of characters.

```javascript
f=m=>(g=(y,X,V)=>m.map(r=>r.map((v,x)=>V?v>f&(x-X)**2+y*y<V-8?r[x]=n--:0:v<f?g(-y,x,'0x'+v):n++)|y++))(n=0)|n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY7NDoIwEITvPAUn2UJb8edgiIW3ICSEQ6tANFIMmKZNeHdEEyMYNR68bHZ2Z77MkSve7prD@UJkvc/7vmAVC6FkYHCCY8TCilb8DA0Lm/sCCuvhGkcqLGagSYJcd@kZ12xjsomaVGdMEhL4gdoWUQnEYI0dXzueQoH0PNSZYSCQzEed7He1bOtTTk91CQWk9nxury3bTimljlJOhsfCyhCy3iQWDxP/NeE/TZOImAK@ENYfCPxnwurhEn8giFFGTAlcvPJG6ttvrITirx1vrfor)

#### How?

The [quadrance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry#Quadrance) of two points \$A_1=(x_1,y_1)\$ and \$A_2=(x_2,y_2)\$ is defined as:

$$Q(A_1,A_2)=(x_2−x_1)^2+(y_2−y_1)^2$$

Considering integer coordinates, it looks as follows:

$$\begin{matrix}
&8&5&4&5&8\\
&5&2&1&2&5\\
&4&1&\bullet&1&4\\
&5&2&1&2&5\\
&8&5&4&5&8
\end{matrix}$$

Therefore:

- a type A antidote located at \$A_1\$ is able to kill a virus located at \$A_2\$ if \$Q(A_1,A_2)<2\$
- a type B antidote located at \$A_1\$ is able to kill a virus located at \$A_2\$ if \$Q(A_1,A_2)<3\$

Conveniently, this exclusive upper bound (\$2\$ or \$3\$) can be obtained by converting the antidote character from hexadecimal to decimal and subtracting \$8\$:

- \$\text{A}_{16} - 8_{10} = 2_{10}\$
- \$\text{B}_{16} - 8_{10} = 3_{10}\$

#### Commented

```javascript
f =                      // named function, because we use it to test if a character
                         // is below or above 'm'
m => (                   // m[] = input matrix
  g = (                  // g is a recursive function taking:
    y,                   //   y = offset between the reference row and the current row
    X,                   //   X = reference column
    V                    //   V = reference value, prefixed with '0x'
  ) =>                   //
    m.map(r =>           // for each row r[] in m[]:
      r.map((v, x) =>    //   for each value v at position x in r[]:
        V ?              //     if V is defined:
          v > f &        //       if v is equal to 'v'
          (x - X) ** 2 + //       and the quadrance between the reference point and
          y * y          //       the current point
          < V - 8 ?      //       is less than the reference value read as hexa minus 8:
            r[x] = n--   //         decrement n and invalidate the current cell
          :              //       else:
            0            //         do nothing
        :                //     else:
          v < f ?        //       if v is either 'a' or 'b':
            g(           //         do a recursive call:
              -y,        //           pass the opposite of y
              x,         //           pass x unchanged
              '0x' + v   //           pass v prefixed with '0x'
            )            //         end of recursive call
          :              //       else:
            n++          //         increment n
      ) | y++            //   end of inner map(); increment y
    )                    // end of outer map()
  )(n = 0)               // initial call to g with y = n = 0
  | n                    // return n
```

Comment: thanks @Arnauld, can you also explain the code?

Comment: @KiaraDan Done.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>33</s> <s>30</s> 29 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2F.•s¯}˜?•2ô€Â2ä`.:S¶¡øJ»}'v¢
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyE3vUcOi4kPra0/PsQeyjA5vedS05nCT0eElCXpWwYe2HVp4eIfXod216mWHFv3/r6SkVFZWxlWWBMQgOhFMA0UB) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaCkU6nDpeRfWgLh2Vf@N3LTe9SwqPjQ@trTc@yBLKPDWx41rTncZHR4SYKeVfChbYcWHt7hdWh3rXrZoUX/dQ5ts/8frVRWFpNXVqako6CUCGeVgQWTwHxMASCRiJBKKkuKyUsCCyQmweTLECwgkVSWCFaZVAYCYFMSE8HsRJAkCAJNVIoFAA).

Port of [*@Jitse*'s Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188952/52210), so make sure to upvote him!
-1 byte thanks to *@Jitse*.

**Explanation:**

The legacy version has the advantage of being able to zip/transpose a string-list, where the new version would need an explicit `S` and `J`, since it only works with character-lists. But, the new version is still 3 bytes shorter by using `€Â` in combination with a shorter compressed string. In the legacy version, `€` would only keep the last value on the stack inside the map, but in the new version, it will keep all values on the stack inside the map.

```python
2F                  # Loop 2 times:
  .•s¯}˜?•          #  Push compressed string "vbvabbca"
   2ô               #  Split it into parts of size 2: ["vb","va","bb","ca"]
     €Â             #  Bifurcate (short for duplicate & reverse copy) each:
                    #   ["vb","bv","va","av","bb","bb","ca","ac"]
       2ä           #  Split it into two parts:
                    #   [["vb","bv","va","av"],["bb","bb","ca","ac"]]
         `          #  Push both those lists separated to the stack
          .:        #  Replace all strings once one by one in the (implicit) input-string
            S       #  Then split the entire modified input to a list of characters
             ¶¡     #  Split that list by newlines into sublists of characters
               ø    #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
                J   #  Join each inner character-list back together to a string again
                 »  #  And join it back together by newlines
}'v¢               '# After the loop: count how many "v" remain
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•s¯}˜?•` is `"vbvabbca"`.

Comment: You don't need `bc` => `ba` if you apply `bv` => `ba` before `av` => `ac`. Thus `.•6øнãI•` (compressed form of `"bvavbaac") is enough, saving 2 bytes.

Comment: @Grimy It results in 1 instead of 3 for [the last test case](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyE3vUcMis8M7Luw9vNgTyDQ6vOVR05rDTUaHlyRYBR/admjh4R1eh3bXqpcdWvT/v5KSUlJZEldSYhlXWWISV1kZkC6D0WVcSWWJQBUA) however.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen two replacement steps instead of three seems to [do the trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188948/virus-vs-antidotes-code-golf/188952#188952) after all

Comment: @Jitse Thanks. The compression string is 2 bytes shorter, but I do now need `.:` (replace all once) instead of `:` (keep replacing all until it is no longer present). Still -1, though. :) Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>211</s> <s>209</s> <s>204</s> 202 bytes

```java
m->{int i=m.length,j,c=0,f,t,I,J;for(;i-->0;)for(j=m[i].length;j-->0;c+=m[i][j]>98?f/9:0)for(f=t=9;t-->0;)try{f-=m[I=i+t/3-1][J=j+t%3-1]==98||m[I][J]<98&(I-=i-J+j)*I==1?1:0;}finally{continue;}return c;}
```

Modification of my answer for the [*All the single eights* challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175766/52210).
-9 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rVNNT4QwEL37K5pNNEU@3I2XZWvXGE9soh48Eg6lgrZC2ZQBs1n57WspmOzBJcZ4IeW9mXkzLzOStcyXL@8HXrC6Rg9MqP0ZQkJBpnPGM/TY/1oAcczfmI6TOEGlQwzcnZlPDQwER49IIYoOpb/e97GClkGRqVd486TH6dzLPfAib0PySmMifH89J07/lrSMRTLGEmkJ7lowlsk6XN7mV@FqbmNzCjQkMCSD3u1z3wRGVLhwde0vknhDpQvn/ZPScPn5aUgDJjfh8gJHPhX@xpXOZUTp4naxmpMuF4oVxW7PKwVCNRnpdAaNVoiT7kD66bZNWpjpxiHbSryg0niEn0EL9WqcYM5gEGQ1YJV9oG@PBhihWdvOAqjuDXynNdthxzvJWKKz3k5VZP9esZ1oMp1Q@6Nc2qanaqYTw7H0950cUX/LOkmlLTvd4YQhx9diF8n6c3RSgz3PuxqyMqgaCLZmx6BQeBapbQMrNBuN7W9hyGOr0hnFf8iT5riDBkQR2G5q09qwt5g5Y6mf1J4aGORcFXBcToSOc3WHLw)

**Explanation:**

```java
m->{                           // Method with char-matrix parameter & int return-type
  int i=m.length,              //  Amount of rows
      j,                       //  Amount of columns
      c=0,                     //  Virus-counter, starting at 0
      f,                       //  Flag-integer
      t,I,J;                   //  Temp-integers
  for(;i-->0;)                 //  Loop over the rows of the matrix
    for(j=m[i].length;j-->0    //   Inner loop over the columns
        ;c+=                   //     After every iteration: increase the counter by:
            m[i][j]>98         //      If the current cell contains a 'v'
             f/9               //      And the flag is 9:
                               //       Increase the counter by 1
            :0)                //      Else: leave the counter unchanged by adding 0
      for(f=t=9;               //    Reset the flag to 9
          t-->0;)              //    Loop `t` in the range (9, 0]:
         try{f-=               //     Decrease the flag by:
           m[I=i+t/3-1]        //      If `t` is 0, 1, or 2: Look at the previous row
                               //      Else-if `t` is 6, 7, or 8: Look at the next row
                               //      Else (`t` is 3, 4, or 5): Look at the current row
            [J=j+t%3-1]        //      If `t` is 0, 3, or 6: Look at the previous column
                               //      Else-if `t` is 2, 5, or 8: Look at the next column
                               //      Else (`t` is 1, 4, or 7): Look at the current column
            ==98               //      And if this cell contains a 'b'
            ||m[I][J]<98       //      Or if there is an 'a'
              &(I-=i-J+j)*I==1?//      in a vertical/horizontal adjacent cell:
               1               //       Decrease the flag by 1
            :0;                //      Else: leave the flag unchanged by decreasing with 0
         }finally{continue;}   //     Catch and ignore any ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions,
                               //     which is shorter than manual checks
  return c;}                   //  And finally return the virus-counter as result
```

Comment: @ceilingcat The `*I>0?1:0;` will break the second test case, but thanks for the catch to finally for -2.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl (`-00lp`), 82 bytes

Using regex to replace `v` by space, then count the `v`s

```
/.
/;$,="(|..{@-})";$;="(|.{@-,@+})";$_=s/(a$,|b$;)\Kv|v(?=$,a|$;b)/ /s?redo:y/v//
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##NYlBCsIwEEX3OYWUWSSYZrpxYwjt3isIksEuhGJKUwbEeHVjmiJ8eLz/5nGZTjmjEWhBu0YmY95D@1GNBVu1mB6O9bi5iNKDTgRWXS@cWPYOtE9gSeEBY7@M93B@ISPmzCzKhN/BmxJXCmIStAVPe@A/uTRffv6GeX2EZ8xt103zDw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 39 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔⪫υ⸿θＰθ≔⁰ηＦθ«≧⁺›⁼ιv⁺№ＫＭb№ＫＶaηι»⎚Ｉη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5NS8QwEIbPm18ReppAhb3vSYqIQpei4MnLZIlNMCZtPsaD@NvjdIvsaSbPM3lnLhbTJaJv7ds6byQ8haWW15JcmEEpOdVsofbSqZO4z9nNAZ6jCxvq3lOnermyGasvbuE/Bdbb4LGXll8fMUnG8kccRlx29@JmW2DyNffyMRksJsHDWtFncJxMW/BmYYiVQydjPscYkwHmnd7sTbzFcDb1C0O4WuyUUvvmw3Q9abv9VwzeYAJudzhgLmCVOrWmSQuNJAi1IOJK/5WEJmROot2R/wM) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔⪫υ⸿θＰθ
```

Join the input strings with `\r` characters and draw the result to the canvas.

```
≔⁰η
```

Clear the number of live virii.

```
Ｆθ«
```

Loop over the characters in the input.

```
≧⁺›⁼ιv⁺№ＫＭb№ＫＶaη
```

If the current character is a virus and there are no adjacent `b`s in any direction or `a`s orthogonally then increment the number of live virii.

```
ι»
```

Repeat with the next character.

```
⎚Ｉη
```

Clear the canvas and print the total number of live virii.